# Scrapy stucked in 400 error when scraping https://www.watsons.com.sg/

Tags: redirect, get, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this webpage: "https://www.watsons.com.sg/" but scrapy always result in 400 error. Attached the scrapy run log as reference here:

```
['diffmarts.pipelines.DiffmartsPipeline']  
2019-01-01 21:17:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened  
2019-01-01 21:17:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)  
2019-01-01 21:17:15 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://queue.watsons.com.sg/?c=aswatson&e=watsonprdsg&ver=v3-java-3.5.2&cver=62&cid=zh-CN&l=PoC+Layout+SG&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.watsons.com.sg%2F>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2019-01-01 21:17:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-01-01 21:17:17 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Scraper close failure
```

I have tried inspect source in chrome and post and the content can be retrieved back by simple "get". So there should be no protection on the web site. Wonder what is wrong. Appreciate if anyone can offer suggestions or helps. Thanks.

Comment: your crawler is getting blocked. You are most likely missing some headers or have user agent header identify you as a bot. Could you post your spider code and `settings.py` ?

Comment: Visit `Network calls` There i found a call `https://in.hotjar.com/api/v1/client/sites/277609/visit-data?sv=5` that might be helpful.

Comment: I finally realized that we need to hard code the redirected url as the start url. That way the missing "/" causing 400 error will not happen. Thanks for all the helps and comments

Answer (score 1):

Allow redirection in your spider. website is being redirected to some page then from that page redirect back to the main page.